# How to get methods from HTTP::Daemon

Tags: perl

How can I find out the `$code` and `$mess` in [HTTP::Daemon](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Daemon) module? In cpan the usage is as

```
$c->send_status_line( $code, $mess, $proto )
```

but I dont know where/how to get `$code`, `$mess` from.

Like, `send_error($code)` is used as `send_error(RC_FORBIDDEN)` which I found from someone's code online, where did he get `RC_FORBIDDEN` from?
Have been playing with the following code. Sorry for the formatting and many thanks to @choroba for formatting it for me.

```
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use HTTP::Daemon;
    use HTTP::Status;
    use LWP;

    my $daemon = HTTP::Daemon->new or die;
    my $d = HTTP::Daemon->new(
    LocalAddr => '0.0.0.0',
    LocalPort => '5000',
    );
    printf ("\n\n   URL of webserver is %s, show this script with %stest\n", 
    $d->url, $d->url);

    while (my $client_connection = $d->accept)  
            {
                new_connection($client_connection);
            }
    sub new_connection 
    { 
    my $client_connection = shift;
    printf "new connection\n";
    while (my $request = $client_connection->get_request) 
    {
        if (my $pid = fork)
            {
                print "Child created : $pid\n";
            }
        elsif (!defined $pid)
            {
                die "Cannot fork $!\n";
            }
        else
            {
                my $address_of_client = $client_connection->peerhost();
                my $port_of_client = $client_connection->peerport();
    print "Connection from client $address_of_client on port 
    $port_of_client\n";
                print "  request\n";
                    if ($request->method eq 'GET' and $request->uri->path 
    eq "/test") 
                        {
                            $client_connection->send_file_response(RC_OK);
                            #$client_connection->send_status_line(200);
                            #print "OK ";
                            #$client_connection->send_file_response($0);
                        }
                    else 
                        {
                            $client_connection->send_error(RC_NOT_FOUND);
                        }
            }
    $client_connection->close;
    } 
   }
```

Comment: What code and message do you want to send? If you don't want to send any code and message, why do you want to call the method?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation also states

> If `$code` is omitted 200 is assumed. If `$mess` is omitted, then a message corresponding to `$code` is inserted. If `$proto` is missing the content of the `$HTTP::Daemon::PROTO` variable is used.

So, you don't have to specify the arguments at all. Otherwise, just use any of the possible [HTTP status codes](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) for `$code`, and either don't specify the `$mess` to get the default message for the code, or use any message you like.

RC_FORBIDEN is exported from [HTTP::Status](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Status).

Comment: Thanks again @choroba , I tried all that are commented out and no luck. Read that $0 displays the filename that was executed whereas $0 prints the whole script. 

    '$client_connection->send_file_response($0);'

Comment: I am still not able to get my head around this. Someone please clarify this for me.
All I want is to send_status_line back to the client which the module says can do. But Im not getting on the browser. Im getting blank and Im using :
if ($request->method eq 'GET' and $request->uri->path eq "/test")
{
$client_connection->send_status_line();
}

Comment: `send_file_response`, as documented, takes a file name as an argument and sends the file contents. Giving it $0, it returns the contents of the script.